# Erlang - Riak clients

Tags: erlang, client, riak

I am in trouble finding API for the "local Erlang client" for Riak.

Here is what Riak wiki says:

> The local Erlang client is a tightly-integrated part of Riak and the Riak REST interface uses the Erlang client internally. You can find more information about the Erlang-native driver in the edoc API.

The link redirects to the main wiki-page. There is plenty of information on PBC Client though.
How do both clients compare and what are the pros and cons in using one or another?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The API for the native erlang client or edoc is found [here](http://basho.github.io/riak-erlang-client/)

But I would second what Dan says.  However, note that the PBC is still very much at the alpha stage of development and as far as I know does not yet have map reduce capabilities.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using the PBC client. The performance is comparable to the native erlang client. It is also easier to decouple your application code from Riak. The native erlang client requires the entire Riak code base as a dependency.

Answer (score 0):

From Riak 2.0 and on, it is **highly** recommended to use PB (Protocol Buffers) APIs over HTTP APIs. They have become a primary APIs, have more functionality and also is faster than HTTP APIs.

- [Getting Started](http://docs.basho.com/riak/kv/latest/developing/getting-started/erlang/) with Erlang client
- [GitHub repo](https://github.com/basho/riak-erlang-client) for official Riak Erlang client